# Weird seg faults on consecutive calls to the same array

Tags: c, arrays, string, fault

I tried really hard to search for a solution to this but I can't think of good enough keywords.

Currently I'm having troubles grasping the concept behind makeargv and it's usage with triple pointers (I have no idea what ***foo means, it doesn't seem to be as easy of a concept as **foo or *foo). So I made my own:

```
const char **makeargv(char *string, int *numargs) {
  string = string + strspn(string, delims);
  char *copy = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
  int i;
  strcpy(copy, string);

  int numtokens;
  if (strtok(copy, delims) != NULL) {
    for (numtokens = 1; strtok(NULL, delims) != NULL; numtokens++) {}
  }

  strcpy(copy, string);

  const char *results[numtokens+1];

  results[0] = strtok(copy, delims);

  for (i = 1; i < numtokens; i++) {
    results[i] = strtok(NULL, delims);
  }

  results[numtokens+1] = NULL;
  *numargs = numtokens;
  return results;
}
```

Here's the part at where it breaks:

```
void parse_file(char* filename) {
    char* line = malloc(160*sizeof(char));
    FILE* fp = file_open(filename);
    int i = 0;
    int numargs = 0;
    int *pointer = &numargs;


    while((line = file_getline(line, fp)) != NULL) {
      if (strlen(line) == 1){
        continue;
      }

  const char **args = makeargv(line, pointer);

  printf("%s\n", args[0]);
  printf("%s\n", args[1]);
      /* This prints out args[0], but then args[1] causes a seg fault. Even if I replace
         the args[1] with another args[0] it still causes a seg fault */

}
fclose(fp);
free(line);
}
```

I have a working array of strings. However when I try to print out the strings in the array, I can only print 1 of my choice and then it seg faults for any subsequent calls. lets pretend my array of strings is argv[3] = {"Yes", "no", "maybe"},  if i call argv[0], it will let me call "Yes", but any other calls (even if i call argv[0] again) do not work and cause a segfault. I can call any of the elements in the array, but once i call one the rest cease to work causing segfaults.

Help please? D: This is in C.

Comment: Instead of describing what you encountered, you should create [a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm sorry I was in transit at the time because I was having problems with copy and paste for some weird reason on the computer I was on. I've fixed it now, any chance you could take a look now? :D

Answer (score 1):

```
const char *results[numtokens+1];
```

This array "results" is a local variable, it is only available inside of "makeargv".

You'd better use malloc:

```
results = malloc(numtokens+1)
```

And I believe there is memory leak in your code.
You will not be able to free the memory for "char *copy"

```
char *copy = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **makeargv(char *string, int *numargs) {
    static const char *delims = " \t\n";
    string = string + strspn(string, delims);
    char *copy = malloc(strlen(string) + 1), *p = copy;
    strcpy(copy, string);

    int numtokens;
    for (numtokens = 0; strtok(p, delims); ++numtokens, p = NULL);

    char **results = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(numtokens+1));
    strcpy(copy, string);

    int i;
    p = copy;
    for (i = 0; i < numtokens; ++i, p = NULL)
        results[i] = strtok(p, delims);
    results[i] = NULL;
    *numargs = numtokens;
    return results;
}

FILE *file_open(char *filename){
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!fp){
        perror("file_open");
        exit(1);
    }
    return fp;
}

void parse_file(char* filename) {
    char* line = malloc(160*sizeof(char));
    FILE* fp = file_open(filename);
    int i = 0, numargs = 0;

    while(fgets(line, 160, fp)){
        if (*line == '\n')
            continue;

        char **args = makeargv(line, &numargs);
        for(i = 0;i<numargs;++i)
            printf("%s\n", args[i]);
        printf("\n");

        if(args[0])
            free(args[0]);
        free(args);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(line);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    parse_file(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```